# Что делать если таблица перешла в неоднозначное состояние?

Tags: mysql

Есть БД `db_name`, в которой находится таблица `table_name`. Взаимодействие с этой БД выполнялось через приложение, в котором есть только один запрос (INSERT). То есть приложение выполняет только вставку данных и больше ничего. Но в определённый момент ПО выдало исключение `Table 'db_name.table_name' doesn't exist`. Я зашла через phpmyadmin и эта таблица была в списке. Я могла даже просмотреть список колонок. Файлы `table_name.ibd`, но нет `table_name.frm`. БД находится в локальной сети. Доступ к ней и файловой системе только у меня. Я никаких правок не делала. При попытке просмотреть таблицу в phpmyadmin, выдавало ошибку `table doesn't exists`. Удалить тоже не могла по этой причине. Удалилa .ibd - таблица пропала с списка. Создала идентичную таблицу, но с другим именем, ибо пишет `table 'table_name' already exists`. Переименовать новую таблицу тоже не могу по той же причине. Может кто объяснить из-за чего могла возникнуть такая проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Из-за нештатного выключения питания устройства или из-за зависания?

Comment: *из-за чего могла возникнуть такая проблема* Сбой файловой системы. Причин - вагон, но наиболее вероятная уже указана выше. *как её решить?* Если старый .ibd удалён "не совсем" (есть где-то копия) - остановить сервер, вернуть файл на место, запустить сервер, выполнить для данной таблицы DROP TABLESPACE и IMPORT TABLESPACE.

Comment: @Akina `ALTER TABLE 'table_name' IMPORT TABLESPACE` вернул ошибку `Table 'db_name.table_name' doesn't exist`. `DROP TABLESPACE 'table_name'` вернул `Table storage engine 'InnoDB' does not support the create option 'TABLESPACE or LOGFILE GROUP'`.